# Java Convert UTC to PDT/PST with Java 8 time library

Tags: java, spring, time, java-8

I would like to use built-in Java 8 time library to convert from UTC to PST/PDT.

I am writing a program that talks to an API that returns a list of objects according to a time frame. E.g. objects created/modified from a certain date time.

My program uses `LocalDateTime` and the value is always in UTC.
The API accepts PST/PDT.
"The time zone represented in all API responses is PST/PDT. Similarly, *CompanyName* asks that you make all time zone convertions and submit any dateTime requests in PST/PDT." -- quote from API documentation

I think what they mean by PST/PDT is that the time value should reflect whether it is in day-light-saving or not.
E.g. the time value changes twice a year.

If that is the case, **is there a practical/conventional way to convert from UTC to PST/PDT without manually figuring out if it is in day-light-saving time by looking at the exact date?**

**UPDATE**

The API returns the objects in JSON format.
My app send a request to their API with a query parameter `api.com/objects?modified-date=${yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}`

I am currently using the following method to do the conversion:

```
public static String toSsTimeStr(LocalDateTime utcTime){
    String pattern  = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(utcTime, ZoneOffset.UTC, ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));

    String timeStr = zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern));
    return timeStr;
}
```

**Will this help adjust the day-light-saving time, in other words, return the correct value according to the current day-light-saving-time status for me?**

Thank you.

Comment: What is the data type of such "dateTime" values? If `String`, what is the format?

Comment: @Andreas My Model/Entity uses LocalDateTime class. This value will be retrieve from my own database, which is always in UTC.

Comment: I was asking about the API: *"The time zone **represented** in all API responses is PST/PDT. Similarly, CompanyName asks that you make all time zone convertions and submit any **dateTime** requests in PST/PDT."*

Comment: @Andreas I do not know about that, it is a third party API that I have no control of. My app is going to synchronize some information using their API. It is returned as JSON the format is the standard yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.

Comment: @Minjun.Y Put clarifications to your Question in your Question, not the comments.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> My program uses LocalDateTime and the value is always in UTC.

A `LocalDateTime` has no time zone at all, so it is *not* in UTC.

For a moment in UTC, use the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class. This represents a moment on the timeline in up to nanosecond resolution.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

To adjust into a time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviations like `PST` & `PDT` so commonly seen in the mainstream media. They are not real time zones, not standardized, and are not even unique(!). Use [proper time zone names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in `continent/region` format.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zoneId );
```

It sounds like your data sink has the poor design of taking an input of a string that represents a date-time value *assumed* to be in `America/Los_Angeles` time zone but lacking any indicator (no offset-from-UTC, no time zone).

To get such a string, lacking any offset or zone, use the predefined [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) named [`ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME). You will get a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format like this: `2011-12-03T10:15:30`.

```
String output = zdt.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME );
```

Your data sink omits the `T` from the middle, so replace with SPACE.

```
output = output.replace( `T` , " " );
```

If your data sink expects only whole seconds, you can truncate any fractional second from your date-time value.

```
zdt = zdt.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS );
```

Going the other direction, from string to object, define a formatter, parse as a `LocalDateTime` and apply the assumed time zone.

```
String input = "2011-12-03 10:15:30";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" );
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , formatter );
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( zoneId );
```

Comment: I am currently using the **proper time zone names** America/Los_Angeles" to convert the **LocalDateTime** object in UTC. If I remember right, today is in daylight saving time so it is 7 hours behind. When the daylight-saving-time is over, will the result still be correctly which is 8 hours behind?

Comment: `instant.atZone(zoneId)` seems more convenient than `ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zoneId)`. --- Typo: `ZoneId.of`

Comment: @Andreas  Yes, thanks, that is better, clearer. I never noticed that method before.

Comment: Note latest [comment by OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447216/java-convert-utc-to-pdt-pst-with-java-8-time-library#comment64300633_38447216): *It is returned as JSON the format is the standard yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.* So, not ISO.

Comment: @Minjun.Y The `ZonedDateTime` handles the Daylight Saving Time (DST) adjustments for you, that's it's job. `LocalDateTime` does *not*! Use `LocalDateTime` only when you have no time zone in mind at all, like "Christmas starts at midnight on the 25th of December this year".

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for the Clarification, that helps. I also updated my question with some clarification.

Comment: It would be better to create an appropriate formatter, rather than using ISO + replace, e.g. `DateTimeFormatter jsonDateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US)`

Comment: @Andreas That's a matter of taste in this particular case. The SPACE instead of T actually *is* compliant with ISO 8601 as a variation though not canonical. So I don't consider the `String::replace` to be crude mangling. Using the named formatter constant plus a call to `replace` seems to be more self-documenting as to my intention of using the variation of ISO 8601.

Comment: But if you have to do it in many places, it's better for the formatter to produce the correct result, rather than having to remember to add `replace()` every time. It's also better for performance. All assuming you use a global, shared formatter instance. Of course, in this particular case, since OP needs timezone handling too, a static helper method is likely the best option, so there may only be one line with `replace()` anyway.

Comment: @Andreas Agreed. Really, java.time should have more formatters pre-defined, such as this space-instead-of-T variation and the “basic” variations where most delimiters are removed.

Comment: Code  at the end of the answer is incorrect. Parsing throws an exception.

Comment: @expert Fixed. Forgot to pass `formatter` as the second argument to `parse` method.  `LocalDateTime.parse( input , formatter );` instead of `LocalDateTime.parse( input );`  If the formatter is not explicitly passed, the default ISO 8601 parser is used by default. The ISO 8601 format requires a `T` in the middle rather than a SPACE (unless both sending and receiving parties agree to a SPACE).

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
ZoneId zid = ZoneId.of(ZoneId.SHORT_IDS.get("PST"));
return LocalDate.now(zid)
```

The SHORT_IDS is a documented way of getting the zoneId based on recognized TZ abbreviations.
[Documentation, FYR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#SHORT_IDS)