# How to convert the UTC date into PST date in java -simpledateformat

Tags: java, timezone, talend, simpledateformat, utc

I am trying to use the simpledateformat function but i am continuously getting errors as "Unparseable date:"

Currently the time which is stored in a `string testtime=2021-09-14T21:15:09.863Z;`//UTC time
I would want to convert this into PST time in the same format using T and Z notation;

```
Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm.sss'Z'").parse(testtime); 

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm.sss'Z", Locale.US);

 dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));

System.out.println("PRINTING the TIME in PST"+dateFormat.format(date1.getTime()));
```

What is missing here,please advise?

Comment: `HH:mm.sss` != `21:15:09.863`. Change it to `HH:mm:ss.SSS`

Comment: Do not longer use SimpleDateFormat and the outdated java.util.Date API. Use the modern java.time API.

Comment: I too recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `TimeZone`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `Instant`, `ZoneId` and `ZonedDateTime`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Is something missing? Always when you ask about code that does not work as expected include *desired result* and *how observed result differs*. If you see any error message, paste it into your question. We can understand your question and your reason for asking much better that way and can hence help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use java.time and you need no formatter

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. I am assuming that by PST you mean North American Pacific Standard Time (America/Vancouver or America/Los_Angeles). Other interpretations exist that are just as valid.

```
    String testtime = "2021-09-14T21:15:09.863Z";
    
    Instant instant1 = Instant.parse(testtime);
    ZoneId desiredZone = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
    ZonedDateTime pstDateTime = instant1.atZone(desiredZone);
    
    System.out.println("PRINTING the TIME in PST: " + pstDateTime);
```

Output:

> PRINTING the TIME in PST:
> 2021-09-14T14:15:09.863-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

Oops, we didn’t get PST. We got Pacific Daylight Time or PDT. Wanting PST in September, I doubt that it makes any sense. Unless, of course, you meant Philippines Standard Time or Pitcairn Standard Time.

**ISO 8601:** Your string is in ISO 8601 format. `Instant` and the other classes of java.time parse and print ISO 8601 format as their default, that is, without us specifying any formatter. So I didn’t. The output from `ZonedDateTime` isn’t strictly ISO 8601 format. If you wanted that, you may format the date and time using the builtin `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`:

```
    System.out.println("PRINTING the TIME in PST: "
            + pstDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
```

> PRINTING the TIME in PST: 2021-09-14T14:15:09.863-07:00

### What were you missing?

Apart from using the long outdated and troublesome classes:

- Never hardcode `Z` as a literal in your format pattern string. In means UTC so you need to parse and format it as an offset, or you will get incorrect result in most cases.
- In particular printing `Z` after the PST time is wrong. Instead we want offset -08:00 for PST and -07:00 for PDT as in my output above.
- As others have pointed out there is a typo in the time part of your format pattern string both times: `HH:mm.sss`. It should be `HH:mm.ss.SSS` for two-digit seconds and three-digit milliseconds. This typo caused the exception that you probably got.
- Don’t rely on `PST` or other three letter abbreviations for time zones. As I said, they have multiple interpretation. Use a time zone ID like America/Vancouver, so in the *region/city* format.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 1):

Your format does not match your input, specifically, `HH:mm.sss` does not match `21:15:09.863`.

Change the format to `HH:mm:ss.SSS`

And then start making use of the newer [Date/Time APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) (ie `java.time`)

## Java 8+

```
String dateInString = "2021-09-14T21:15:09.863Z";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");

OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateInString, formatter);

ZoneId utcTZId = ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC");
ZonedDateTime utcDT = odt.atZoneSameInstant(utcTZId);
System.out.println(utcDT.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME));

ZoneId laTZId = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" );
ZonedDateTime laDT = utcDT.withZoneSameInstant(laTZId);
System.out.println(laDT.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME));
```

which prints...

```
2021-09-14T21:15:09.863Z[Etc/UTC]
2021-09-14T14:15:09.863-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
```

[Java Convert UTC to PDT/PST with Java 8 time library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447216/java-convert-utc-to-pdt-pst-with-java-8-time-library) was an interesting read

Comment: Thanks for noticing i fixed its working,however i am confused how do i tell the compiler that the captured time in testtime is in UTC and needs to be converted to PST?
Coz everytime i use the "getTimeZone("PST")" it just rewrites the same date whatever is in testtime string,i want to notify that its a UTC time and needs a switch over to PST!

Comment: First, `Date` is agnostic of timezone, so, in your case, it's only a presentation state, which is why when dealing with date/time with an external system, you want to make sure that the value carries time zone information in some way.  You don't tell the compiler anything, that's up to you to make determinations about in your code as the program is running, again, it's one of those reasons why you should either use a dedicated class, ie `ZonedDateTime` or set down rules about what time zone the date/time is coming from.  It's 2 o'clock doesn't mean anything, unless you know WHERE it's 2!